# Output element in comments

Tags: xslt

I need to display HTML-element in comments (for example)

```
<!-- <img src="path" width="100px" height="100px"/> -->
```

I use this approach

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="windows-1251"/>

    <xsl:template match="myNode">
        ...
        <xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates select="image" /></xsl:comment>
        ...
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image">
        <img src="{@src}" width="{@width}px" height="{@height}px" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As a result:

```
<!---->
```

that is the code in the element `xsl:comment` ignored.

How do I display an item in the comments?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation and three possible approaches, depending on the specific task.

Comment: I just edited my answer and think that now it has the solution that you want. Is this so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might be possible to replace

`<xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates select="image" /></xsl:comment>`

with

`<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>`
`<xsl:apply-templates select="image" />`
`<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>`

Haven't tried though.

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> <xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates select="image" /></xsl:comment>
> ```
>
> As a result:
>
> ```
> <!---->
> ```
>
> that is the code in the element
>   xsl:comment ignored

**[The XSLT 1.0 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Comments) says**:

> It is an error if instantiating the
>   content of xsl:comment creates nodes
>   other than text nodes. An XSLT
>   processor may signal the error; if it
>   does not signal the error, it must
>   recover by ignoring the offending
>   nodes together with their content.
>
> How do I display an item in the
>   comments?

It depends what is meant for "display": in a browser:

```
&lt;-- <xsl:apply-templates select="image" /> -->
```

may be useful, provided the result of `<xsl:apply-templates/>` aboveis just simple text (not markup).

If to "display" means to provide the result as text, then DOE, if allowed by the XSLT processor, may give us the wanted result:

<--
   Some text  -->

Finally, if it is required that what should be inside the "comment" should be markup and it should be displayed as markup, then this is rather challenging. In this case one has to use:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
```

and should present every XML lexical item with its desired serialization (i.e. escaped).

This is how the XPath Visualizer constructs its output.

**Here is a small transformation that demonstrates the first two approaches**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
      &lt;-- Hello, World -->

  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;--</xsl:text>
   Hello,world! --<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**this transformation, when applied on any XML document (not used), produces**:

```
      &lt;-- Hello, World --&gt;

  <--
   Hello,world! -->
```

Both "comments" may be viewed as comments in a browser, while only the second is presented as comment in free text.

**The third approach (most probably what you want) is illustrated below**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  &lt;-- <xsl:apply-templates select="image"/> -->

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="image">
  &lt;img src="<xsl:value-of select="@src"/>"
      width="<xsl:value-of select="@width"/>px"
      height="<xsl:value-of select="@height"/>px"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<image src="http://example.com/yyy.jpg" width="200" height="300"/>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
  &lt;-- 
  &lt;img src="http://example.com/yyy.jpg"
      width="200px"
      height="300px"/&gt;
  --&gt;
```

**viewed in a browser as**:

<-- 
  <img src="http://example.com/yyy.jpg"
      width="200px"
      height="300px"/>
  -->

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Comments:

The xsl:comment element is instantiated to create a comment node in the result tree. The content of the xsl:comment element is a template for the string-value of the comment node.

> For example, this
>
> `<xsl:comment>This file is
>   automatically generated. Do not
>   edit!</xsl:comment>`
>
> would create the comment
>
> `<!--This file is automatically
>   generated. Do not edit!-->`
>
> It is an error if instantiating the
>   content of xsl:comment creates nodes
>   other than text nodes. An XSLT
>   processor may signal the error; if it
>   does not signal the error, it must
>   recover by ignoring the offending
>   nodes together with their content.
>
> It is an error if the result of
>   instantiating the content of the
>   xsl:comment contains the string `--` or
>   ends with `-`. An XSLT processor may
>   signal the error; if it does not
>   signal the error, it must recover by
>   inserting a space after any occurrence
>   of `-` that is followed by another `-` or
>   that ends the comment.

So, in order to do what you want you need to use DOE mechanism.

As example, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="windows-1251"/>
    <xsl:template match="img">
        <img src="{.}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="vResult">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <html>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$vResult"/>
            <xsl:comment>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($vResult)"
                                     mode="encode"/>
            </xsl:comment>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="encode">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name())"
                      disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="encode"/>
        <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="encode"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'>')"
                      disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" mode="encode">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name())"
                      disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="encode"/>
        <xsl:text>/></xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="encode">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',name(),'=&quot;',.,'&quot;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
    <img>http://example.org/image1.jpg</img>
    <img>http://example.org/image2.jpg</img>
    <img>http://example.org/image3.jpg</img>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <img src="http://example.org/image1.jpg">
    <img src="http://example.org/image2.jpg">
    <img src="http://example.org/image3.jpg">
    <!--<img src="http://example.org/image1.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://example.org/image2.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://example.org/image3.jpg"/>-->
</html>
```

**Note**: `node-set` extension function for two pass transformation. `disable-output-escaping` attribute for `xsl:value-of` instruction.

Comment: @Alejandro: I can not use `node-set` in our project (I have no way to activate this feature)

Comment: @Kalinin: The use of `node-set` extension function is about two pass transformation, it's not about what you need: disabling output escaping so `<` character isn't output as an entity reference `&lt;`. Of course, if you don't use a two pass transformation you have to built the contente template for your "pseudoelements" the same way I did in those mode "encode" templates. Also, I'm sure your processor has the `node-set` extension function but under a diferent namespace. Which XSLT processor do you use?

Answer (score 1):

As said before by Dimitri you can't use the xsl:comment instruction.

If your purpose is simply to comment a fragment of tree, the simplest way is to put the comments markers as text (unescaped) like this :

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="image" /><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
```

instead of :

```
<xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates select="image" /></xsl:comment>
```

and you will obtain exactly this

```
<!-- <img src="path" width="100px" height="100px"/> -->
```

used with msxml and saxon

Comment: I fail to see how this answer differs from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3933175/272735