# <xsl:comment> issue

Tags: xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Output element in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932152/output-element-in-comments)

I'm trying to comment a node during an xsl transformation in this way

```
Doesn't work:
<xsl:comment><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:comment>
```

but what I get is an empty comment, but removing the comment element I get the correct node

```
This is correct:
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

Why the copy-of element doesn't work inside the comment one? Is there a solution or I'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Ian this is a duplicate.

In any case, what you probably want is ...

```
<xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:comment>
```

The reason? Comments cannot contain child nodes. They are an atomic node type with a text property (the comment content).

Comment: xsl:value-of inside xsl:comment should do exactly the same as xsl:copy-of - it gives you the string value of the selected node. Presumably from the evidence given, the string value is empty, and what they want is some representation of the markup.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straight-forward way to generate the textual representation of an element inside a comment.

**Here is a short one, using an inline extension function (in C#):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
     xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl my">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:value-of select="my:stringize(someElement)"/>
      </xsl:comment>
     </xsl:template>

     <msxsl:script language="c#" implements-prefix="my">
      public string stringize(XPathNavigator doc)
      {
       return doc.OuterXml;
      }
     </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied (using the .NET XslCompiledTransform XSLT processor) on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <someElement>someValue</someElement>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<!--<someElement>someValue</someElement>-->
```

**There are different ways to do the same in pure XSLT** -- see for example the XSLT code of the **[XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** for a good - looking representation of an XML document as Html (an open source product I wrote 12 years ago and which I am not advertizing in any way here)

Answer (score 0):

You could not use `xsl:comment` and use `xsl:text` with DOE.

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <foo>
        <bar attr="test"/>
    </foo>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="foo"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--></xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc><!--<foo>
      <bar attr="test"/>
   </foo>--></doc>
```