# How to include xml inside xsl:comment and maintain indents

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm writing some xsl to transform a book outline in xml into a bunch of individual xml files (one for each chapter, plus some frontmatter, etc).  I'll do this with `<exsl:document>`, and much of the content of the individual files will be written inside the xsl.

I use xsltproc, so xslt 1.0.

I want text comments, which I can get using `<xsl:comment>`, but also some xml that is "commented out".  As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932152/output-element-in-comments), this is not possible using `<xsl:comment>`.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933175) to that question uses `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>` to wrap the commented xml.  This works, except that as soon as you add it, the output no longer gets indented correctly.

For example, the following xsl:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
  <xsl:comment>Text comment</xsl:comment>
  <child><name>A child</name></child>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
  <child><name>commented child</name></child>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
</root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives the xml inside the comment, but no indentation:

```
<root><!--Text comment--><child><name>A child</name></child><!--<child><name>commented child</name></child>--></root>
```

while using this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
  <xsl:comment>Text comment</xsl:comment>
  <child><name>A child</name></child>
  <xsl:comment><child><name>commented child</name></child></xsl:comment>
</root>
</xsl:template>
```

gives nice indentation, but no xml tags in the comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <!--Text comment-->
  <child>
    <name>A child</name>
  </child>
  <!--commented child-->
</root>
```

Is there any way to keep indenting but put xml code inside comments?

Comment: There are some XSLT 1 based libraries like https://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/ that allow you to serialize nodes to XML strings so that way, in XSLT 1, you can build a comment containing the XML serialization of some nodes. Indentation is a difficult issue, it is not clear whether you just want to have the serialized XML inside the comment indented or to expect that serialization to integrate nicely with the indentation of the result tree serialization.

Comment: And of course these days there is XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.8 or 9.8 HE available in a Java, .NET and C/C++ version as an option to delegate the serialization to the XPath 3 `serialize` function.

Comment: Not possible? :)   See my answer!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now it is possible to do the commenting as part of an XML file (not text output) and have the commented text unescaped and indented.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a transformation that can be used to comment out any XML node or fragment and that**:

1. Does **not** use DOE
2. Preserves indentation
3. Even tries to express nested comments -- doesn't ignore comments or throw an error when a comment is encountered for commenting:

=============================

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;!--&#xA;'"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="escapeToText"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;-->'"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="*" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', name())"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="escapeToText"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'>'"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="escapeToText"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/', name(), '>')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', name(), '=&quot;')"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="string(.)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;'"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;?', name(), ' ', ., ' ?>')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;!CM ', ., 'CM>')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="escapeDoubleDash">
   <xsl:param name="pText"/>

   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($pText, '--')">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, '--')"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="'!-!-'"/>
       <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '--')"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$pText"/></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied against any source xml document**, for example this:

```
<input>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <type-10-num>1</type-10-num>
    <type-20-num>2</type-20-num>
    <type-20-char>3</type-20-char>
    <type-180-num>4</type-180-num>
    <type-180-char>5</type-180-char>
    <type-180-str>6</type-180-str>
</input>
```

**the wanted, indented result is produced**:

```
<!--
<input>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <type-10-num>1</type-10-num>
    <type-20-num>2</type-20-num>
    <type-20-char>3</type-20-char>
    <type-180-num>4</type-180-num>
    <type-180-char>5</type-180-char>
    <type-180-str>6</type-180-str>
</input>
-->
```

**Here is how a commented-out, very complex XML document looks like** -- let's apply this transformation on ... itself.

For completeness, I have added a comment and a processing instruction before the template matching attributes:

```
  <?somePI x="y" z="t" pqr ?>

  <!-- A Comment node -->
```

And the result is as expected:

```
<!--
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"></xsl:output>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="'<!!-!-
'"></xsl:value-of>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="escapeToText"></xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:value-of select="'
!-!->'"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="*" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('<', name())"></xsl:value-of>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="escapeToText"></xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:value-of select="'>'"></xsl:value-of>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="escapeToText"></xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('</', name(), '>')"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>

  <?somePI x="y" z="t" pqr  ?>

  <!CM  A Comment node CM>
  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', name(), '="')"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="string(.)"></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:value-of select="'"'"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="."></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('<?', name(), ' ', ., ' ?>')"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('<!CM ', ., 'CM>')"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="escapeDoubleDash">
   <xsl:param name="pText"></xsl:param>

   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($pText, '!-!-')">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, '!-!-')"></xsl:value-of>
       <xsl:value-of select="'!-!-'"></xsl:value-of>
       <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '!-!-')"></xsl:with-param>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$pText"></xsl:value-of></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
-->
```

**Update**:

In case you want the commented result to appear as part of an XML document -- that is, not to have `<xsl:output method="text"/>`,
 I suggest adding a special element, say `<MyComment>` and produce the result of the commenting as a text node child of `<MyComment>`. Generally, the xml fragment that is commented will appear with special characters escaped.

But there is one trick -- use CDATA section -- then you will see the text unescaped. This is best seen in an example:

The updated transformation is almost identical to the one provided above, but:

1. There is no `method="text"` in the `<xsl:output>` directive
2. The commented text is a text node of a `<MyComment>` element
3. All "commented XML" -- actually represented as text appears in a CDATA section and is **unescaped**

**Here is the modified transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="MyComment"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <MyComment>
     <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;!--&#xA;'"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="escapeToText"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;-->'"/>
    </MyComment>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="*" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', name())"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="escapeToText"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'>'"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="escapeToText"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/', name(), '>')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', name(), '=&quot;')"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="string(.)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;'"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()" mode="escapeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;?', name(), ' ', ., ' ?>')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;!CM ', ., 'CM>')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="escapeDoubleDash">
   <xsl:param name="pText"/>

   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($pText, '--')">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, '--')"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="'!-!-'"/>
       <xsl:call-template name="escapeDoubleDash">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '--')"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$pText"/></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When we apply this transformation to the following XML document**:

```
<input>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <type-10-num>1</type-10-num>
    <type-20-num>2</type-20-num>
    <type-20-char>3</type-20-char>
    <type-180-num>4</type-180-num>
    <type-180-char>5</type-180-char>
    <type-180-str>6</type-180-str>
</input>
```

**The wanted, unescaped commenting is produced:**

```
<MyComment><![CDATA[<!--
<input>
    <name>Jack</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <type-10-num>1</type-10-num>
    <type-20-num>2</type-20-num>
    <type-20-char>3</type-20-char>
    <type-180-num>4</type-180-num>
    <type-180-char>5</type-180-char>
    <type-180-str>6</type-180-str>
</input>
-->]]></MyComment>
```

We can get rid of the XML comments (`<!--  -->`) and the code that processes "nested comments" -- this is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up, but I think this is backwards from what I need (probably my fault for not being clear).  I have data in an XML file that I want to process to create a new XML output file.  Most of the output file's structure is contained in the XSL file (not the source XML), and I would like the XML output to include "commented out" XML lines (that only exist inside the XSL).  Is there any modification of your solutions to accomplish this?

Comment: @OscarLevin, No modifications -- just add the XML you want to generate within the transformation -- for example: `<xsl:variable name="vmarkupToComment>Your XML Here</xsl:variable>"`. Then at the place in the transformation where you want to generate the commented out text, just have: `<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($vmarkupToComment)/node()" mode="escapeToText"/>` . The `xxx:node-set()` function is necessary only if you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor.